# Viewing/debugging slow save participants

Tags: visual-studio-code

After a recent VS Code update, C# files in my solution began occasionally taking several seconds to save, due to long-running save participants. I would like to view a log of which save participants are handling files on save, and see if any are bumping up against the `files.participants.timeout` setting.

How can I view a listing of which extensions/features engage in the file save pipeline so that I can figure out which one is misbehaving?